# selectRowAtIndexPath: animated: scrollPosition: - Row is "selected"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, nsindexpath

I am using the following code to scroll to the top of a tableView:

```
NSIndexPath *topIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.listTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:topIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

It works great, but I'd like to avoid the target row from being "selected". See image below:

[image]

Any ideas on how to "deselect" the row after this code runs? Or better yet, run this code in a way that doesn't "select" the target row in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[self.listTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:topIndexPath
    atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: ahh, yes that makes much sense, let me test.

Comment: Works beautifully, Thanks Rob